# Filter a pandas row without repetition based on combination of values in separate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows

```
criteria 1  criteria 2  value
         a1    a2          99
         b1    a2          88
         c1    a2          77
         a1    b2          66
         b1    b2          55
         c1    b2          44
         a1    c2          33
         b1    c2          22
         c1    c2          11
```

My intention is to take the rows with best value (3rd column) such that none of the criteria 1 and criteria 2 get repeated in the same columns
Here is my desired result -

```
criteria 1  criteria 2  value
         a1    a2          99
         b1    b2          55
         c1    c2          11
```

Could you please share some ideas to deal with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
df_new = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)
result = df_new.iloc[[0],]
for i in range(1,df_new.criteria1.nunique()):
    df_new = df_new[~df_new.criteria1.isin(result.criteria1)& ~df_new.criteria2.isin(result.criteria2)]
    result=result.append(df_new.iloc[[0],])
```

**Output** (dataframe named 'result')

```
criteria1   criteria2   value
a1               a2     99
b1               b2     55
c1               c2     11
```